# How to know why 'OnCloseQuery' is called - MDI child closed or App Shutdown?

Tags: delphi, mdi

I am currently developing an MDI application.
Every time a new MDI child window is created, it's underlying data is saved on the fly to an SQLite database and the column `open` is set to `1`, so if the user closes the program and reopens it, the windows are restored (also in case of Anything Bad<sup>TM</sup>).
So every document is always present in the database - the only thing that happens if the user clicks "Save" is that the column `persistent` is set to `1`.
Now if an MDI child window is closed, `open` is set to `0` - and every row with `persistent=0 AND open=0` is doomed and will be deleted.

As a result of this behaviour I don't need to ask "Save documents?" on ApplicationClose.
But I **do** need to ask every time an MDI child window is closed.
That would all be easy to do if `Mainform.OnCloseQuery` would be called before `MDIChild.OnCloseQuery`, but sadly that's not the case.

**To sum it up:**
I need a way to know whether `MDIChild.OnCloseQuery` is called because

- the application is shutting down, or
- the MDI child window is being closed.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: computers dont know the "why" they may know , in this case, the which. which function called which function. to know the which , consider a global var on application, that will set to "true" when the application is closed, and you can check it. this is not a "delphi" solution, but a programming solution.

Comment: Of course. A global var which is set to `true` on app shutdown would be great. That is what I meant with "it would be easy if `Mainform.OnCloseQuery` would be called first".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to override the protected virtual method `CloseQuery` in your main form. When that fires you know the app is going down. But the inherited implementation calls `CloseQuery` on the MDI children before firing the `OnCloseQuery` event on the main form.

Here is the `TCustomForm` implementation of `CloseQuery`:

```
function TCustomForm.CloseQuery: Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if FormStyle = fsMDIForm then
  begin
    Result := False;
    for I := 0 to MDIChildCount - 1 do
      if not MDIChildren[I].CloseQuery then Exit;
  end;
  Result := True;
  if Assigned(FOnCloseQuery) then FOnCloseQuery(Self, Result);
end;
```

Notice that the MDI children get their `CloseQuery` notifications before that for `Self`, i.e. the main form.

So in your main form you need:

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm);
  private
    FCloseQueryExecuting: Boolean;
  protected
    function CloseQuery: Boolean; override;
  public
    property CloseQueryExecuting: Boolean read FCloseQueryExecuting;
  end;
```

and then an implementation that looks like this:

```
function TMainForm.CloseQuery: Boolean; 
begin
  FCloseQueryExecuting := True;
  try
    Result := inherited CloseQuery;
  finally
    FCloseQueryExecuting := False;
  end;
end;
```

Then the MDI children can check the state of the main form's `FCloseQueryExecuting` property in their `OnCloseQuery` events.